# SQL: SELECT table and include field/value from another table

Tags: sql, join, subquery, inner-join

what I would like to accomplish is selecting different values from one table and include a field value (which would be selected from another table) from another table.

Here is an example of my statement:

```
SELECT table1.Foo, <- ID
       table1.Bar, <- some value
       (SELECT table2.Baz from table2 <- another value I'd like to select from another table
        WHERE table1.Foo = table2.Foo and table2.Qux = 'A') As value1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Foo = table2.Foo
WHERE table1.Bar = '2'
```

It is very important that value1 is a distinct value. The error that is being thrown is that the subquery (of value1) is containing more than one value.

I would kindly ask you for your help!

Edit: here is some sample data

table1

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Foo         |       Bar        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        ABC       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        XYZ       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

table2

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Foo         |        Baz       |       Qux        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        100       |        A         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        200       |        B         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        150       |        A         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        175       |        B         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Result <- this is what I'd like to achieve

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Foo         |        Bar       |       value1     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        ABC       |        100       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        XYZ       |        150       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Greetings,
Frame

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Well if that subquery would return more than one record, then what is your logic for choosing a single value?

Comment: You are saying "I have a query that returns multiple values, how do I make it return just one value?"  Well, ***you*** need to specify the logic as to how; do you want the `MIN()`, the `MAX()`, the `AVERAGE()`, the first value when ordered by a timestamp column, or some other logic?  The best advice is to give a fully demonstrable example; example data with the results you want, expressing the rules you want to apply.  It may help you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `JOIN` again if you are using `subquery`:

```
select *,
       (select top 1 Baz from table2 where Foo = t1.Foo and Qux = 'A') as value1
from table1 t1;
```

Use `LIMIT` clause instead  `TOP` in case doesn't support.

You can implement `LIMIT` clause as

```
select *,
        (select Baz 
         from table2 
         where Foo = t1.Foo and 
               Qux = 'A' 
         order by Baz -- Use DESC if necessary 
         LIMIT 1) as value1
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: your solution seems to work (I have not fully checked the result yet). What I don't understand, and I can't seem to find a way to display the subquery, is why there are more than one records when selecting with the subquery

Comment: @Frame Then explain in your question why you expect there to be only one record. This is just another reason why you should always give a [mcve] in code questions--it includes DDL, which includes certain constraints/assumptions about the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.Foo,
    t1.Bar,
    t2.Baz AS value1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.Foo = t2.Foo
WHERE
    t2.Qux = 'A';
```

Comment: I would like to get the table2.Baz value that has the same ID (Foo) as the record from table1 and where table2.Qux = 'A'

Comment: @Frame I updated my answer, but your sample data fails to show the logic of what happens if a table1 record should match to multiple table2 records.

Comment: For each ID in table2 there are 3 values that in Qux contain either 'A', 'B' or 'C'. So if I add table2.Qux = 'A' the outcome should be just one record

Comment: Um...my query already does this.  Have you tried running it yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SELECT DISTINCT Statement

`SELECT DISTINCT table1.Foo,
       table1.Bar,
       (SELECT table2.Baz from table2
        WHERE table1.Foo = table2.Foo and table2.Qux = 'A') As value1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
WHERE table1.Foo = table2.Foo AND table1.Bar = '2'`